# How expensive is it to do a query comparing two columns, vs a query on one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I've got a database of photos. I already record the width and height. I'm considering adding an "orientation" column in case someone wants to filter by portrait or landscape.

```sql
-- get landscape orientation photos with one column
select * from photos where orientation = 'landscape';
```

But of course, I could just compare the two columns like this, making the orientation column unnecessary:

```sql
-- get landscape orientation photos by comparing two columns
select * from photos where width > height;
```

If I don't absolutely have to create an extra column, I lean towards not doing it. Just one more thing to maintain. But I wonder if under a heavy load, does the comparison cost a lot more?

Comment: A straight comparison such as `orientation = 'landscape'` with an index on orientation will be significantly faster than an arithmetic comparison. If you make `orientation` a `bit` (e.g, 1 = portrait, 0 = landscape) it will take almost no room and is easy to compute on insert or update.

Comment: Thanks Nick, maybe it's worth setting up then.

Comment: depends on how many photos you have ? 1 million ? comparison wouldn't add load if you don't want to add addl column

Comment: @Nick An Index on a Boolean field is almost next to useless. Assuming the values are spread roughly evenly between 0 and 1 then a table scan will be quicker than an index look up. In general, use of an index needs to get the required records to below 10% of the table total to be worthwhile.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock agreed, if they are spread roughly evenly. In *general* though, photos tend to be far more landscape oriented than they are portrait. A quick scan of one of my photo disks shows around 14-15% in portrait mode.

Comment: In the time it took to ask, it seems to me you could test the veracity of Nick's assertion for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could even make this calculation automatic:

```
ALTER TABLE photo ADD COLUMN orientation enum('landscape', 'portrait') GENERATED ALWAYS AS (if(height>width, 'landscape', 'portrait')),
ADD INDEX o(orientation)
```

You might have some efficiency if there is other sort criteria or the dataset is particularly biased on way or another. Generally binary indexes can rarely be used efficiently unless all the results are in that index as a primary key or compound key.

And square photos?

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=5309de769d7ddcab171cdbbd8aa10e21)

Answer (score 1):

The way to know is to benchmark it on your specific dataset, database (postgresql and mysql are quite different) and version, and hardware.

In my hands, the comparison of one string column to a string constant is very slightly slower than a comparison of two float columns.

The difference is unlikely to be meaningful, and this is unlikely to be the query you are running anyway (you really are going to return every landscape photo from a large dataset with no additional selection criteria?)

Comment: No, my example is simplified. There would be other criteria for sure. Do you have any suggestions on how to get started with benchmarking?

Comment: Do you already have the data?  If so, just track_io_timing on and run the queries with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  If the queries are parameterized, you should write a script that makes up random but realistic parameters, so that the caching effects are measured correctly.  I'd also run the queries in their "natural setting" with whatever programming language you will be using, both because that should be the one you are best at, and it is plausible that your driver/language could affect the outcome.